# Spring Boot OAuth2: How to access the authentication server with custom SSLContext?

Tags: spring, authentication, ssl-certificate

With the Spring Boot 3.1 release [securing the application with SSL](https://spring.io/blog/2023/06/07/securing-spring-boot-applications-with-ssl) is getting more comfortable. Although I'm struggling to add a custom SSLContext to the AuthenticationManager (using JwtAuthenticationProvider) in my application (see [Spring Security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture)).

The AuthenticationManager of my application should communicate with the authentication server using HTTPS with custom certificates (configured in the application properties), but I can't find the place to add the configured SSLContext. In the end the JwtDecoder uses RestTemplate to communicate with the auth server. But overriding the NimbusJwtDecoder e.g. to add SSL support doesn't seem appropriate to me.

Any suggestions how this should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, reading the Spring Security docs the following solution works. Add a custom [`JwtDecoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/JwtDecoder.html) (e.g. based on [`NimbusJwtDecoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/NimbusJwtDecoder.html)) to the security configuration like:

```java
@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(RestTemplateBuilder builder, SslBundles sslBundles, OAuth2ResourceServerProperties oAuth2ResourceServerProperties {
  RestOperations rest = builder.setSslBundle(sslBundles.getBundle("bundleName")).build();
  return NimbusJwtDecoder
          .withIssuerLocation(oAuth2ResourceServerProperties.getJwt().getIssuerUri())
          .restOperations(rest)
          .build();
}
```

Be aware of the `NoSuchSslBundleException` that the [`SslBundles#getBundle(String)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.1/api/org/springframework/boot/ssl/SslBundles.html#getBundle(java.lang.String)) method could throw. Also, an `IllegalStateException` can be thrown if the `SslBundle#createSslContext()` method is invoked later.